# Modulus % give 2 in place of 0

Tags: php, modulus

In php:
the Modulus % gives Remainder of $x divided by $y.

I have tryed this code:

```
<?php
print(100000000165 % 5);
```

result is 2
since it should be 0

Comment: At my system it's `0`. Do you use a 32bit or 64bit version of php?

Comment: You're probably running on a 32-bit PHP, in which the biggest int is about 2 billion. Past that, the numbers wrap around, and 100000000165 becomes 1215752357.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're working on a 32bit system.

The largest integer number in 32bit php is `2147483647`. That means after that (beginning with `2147483648`) it's an overflow and wraps.

Your number is greater than that and so the result is: `(100000000165 % 2147483648) % 5` => `1215752357 % 5` => `2`

---

**Addition: You can build the modulus function by yourself and deal with floats**

```
$largeNumberThatBreaksInteger = 10000000000000000000165;
$modulus = $largeNumberThatBreaksInteger / PHP_INT_MAX - (int)($largeNumberThatBreaksInteger / PHP_INT_MAX) * PHP_INT_MAX;
// results in something like -9.9981352879506E+21. So you can compare it with an epsilon and know if it's 0 or not.
```

[Dealing with floats and epsilon](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)